# How can I send through ajax post a global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok, so I have these two functions. On the first function I change the value of global variable repined and after, I call an ajax post and send the parameter in it.

On the second function, I call the same ajax post and try to send the same value as the one I sent on the first one. but for some reason keeps sending an undefined variable.

```
var window.repinId = 0;

function pinEvent(pinId) {
    window.repinId = pinId;
    $.post( "/pin/create?from=repin&pinId="+pinId )
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#modal-pin-it .modal-body').html(data);
            $('#modal-pin-it').modal('show');
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log('fail!');
        });
    }


function submitPin(repinId) {
    $.post( "/pin/create?from=repin&pinId="+window.repinId, $("#createForm").serialize())
    .done(function (data) {

        $('#modal-pin-it').slideUp('fast', function () {
            $('#modal-pin-it .modal-body').empty();
            $('#modal-pin-it .modal-body').html(data);
        });
        $('#modal-pin-it').slideDown();
        $('#submit-pin').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#submit-pin').hide();
    })
    .fail( function () {
        console.log('fail!');
    });
}
```

Comment: Why `window.repinId`? Why not just `repinId`? You never use that first parameter of the `submitPin` function.

Comment: remove `var` keyword, if you want to declare variable globally. Just `window.repinId = 0;`

Comment: @Tommi Yes was that. Can you post your answer so that I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Posted, but please consider to refactor your code to avoid global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring variable inside object like
`var window.repinId = 0;`
is actually invalid syntax.
To declare variable in global context you need to use
`window.repinId = 0;`
or just
`repinId = 0;` if you already in global context.
Please note, that using of global variables is generally bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

With the second parameter

```
var data = $("#createForm").serializeArray();
data.push('from', 'repin');
data.push('pinId', repinId);

$.post("/pin/create", data).done(function(data) {
    // ...
});
```

From [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
.done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Comment: I keep getting the same result: /pin/create?from=repin&pinId=undefined

Comment: Then it is undefined... How did you call method `pinEvent`? Make a `console.log(pinId);` as first line of this method... But all you did with `?key=value` is a get parameter and you want to make a post request. You work with the second parameter from `$.post` and remove the query-parameter from your url.

Comment: Change `var window.repinId = 0;` to `var repinId = 0;` and change `window.repinId = pinId;` to `repinId = pinId;` and if you want to get the value use `var variable = repinId;`